# aggregate and count unique values in R

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a data set of Vehicle types as factors (11,12,13=type of cars) for each Vehicle type I have a number of Unit Id (=specific cars) I want to count how many uniqe UnitId I have in each vehicle Type.
i tried:
`aggregate(UnitId~VehicleType, test, unique)->res1`

Comment: Try `aggregate(UnitId~VehicleType, test, function(x) length(unique(x)))` or use `with(test, table(UnitId, VehicleType))`

Comment: using `table`, it should be `with(test, colSums(!!table(UnitId, VehicleType)))`

Comment: Or with dplyr: `library(dplyr); test %>% distinct(VehicleType, UnitID) %>% count(VehicleType)`

Comment: Please add a reproducible example for your problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: your code works! thx! is there a way to find out if a UnitId appers in more then one VehicleType?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the updated question, i.e. "is there a way to find out if a UnitId appers in more then one VehicleType"

```
 with(test, names(rowSums(!!table(UnitId, VehicleType))>1))
```

Copy/pasting from the comments based on your original question ("counting unique values by group")

```
aggregate(UnitId~VehicleType, test, function(x) length(unique(x)))
```

Or

```
with(test, colSums(!!table(UnitId, VehicleType)))
```

Or

```
library(data.table)
setDT(test)[, length(unique(UnitId)), VehicleType]
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
test <- data.frame(VehicleType=sample(11:18,60, replace=TRUE), 
  UnitId=sample(1:10, 60, replace=TRUE))
```